# Por que los datos de mi hijo component aparecen vacios Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola tengo un componente padre y un componente hijo, el cual le coloco datos a traves de un @Input() al hijo, pero cuando hago un imprimo en mi `ngOnInit` o mi `ngAfterViewInit` los datos me aparecen como un arreglo vacio, pero en mi html o despues de un SetTimeOut si me aparecen datos. A que se debe esto? Este es mi codigo:

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() data: Data[];
  constructor() { 
    console.log(data) // Da como resultado []
}
  ngOnInit(): void { 
    console.log(data) // Da como resultado []
}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(data) // Da como resultado []
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(data) // Da como resultado mi objeto
    },2000);
  }
  
}
```

Aqui esta como envio la data en el componente padre

```
<app-sidebar [data]="data"></app-sidebar>
```

Comment: Y de dónde obtienes esa data?

Comment: Si deberás mostrar de donde obtienes ese data, por ejemplo si lo obtienes de manera asincrona cuando se crea el componente va [] y ya que se resuelve se actualiza el objeto, y se puede ver en el otro componente ya que es un objeto y se pasan automáticamente por referencia (manejo de memoria). Una solución <app-sidebar [data]="data" *ngIf="data.length>0"></app-sidebar>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para sacar el máximo rendimiento a Angular, necesitamos conocer el ciclo de vida de sus componentes. Cuando se muestra un componente:

1. se llama al `constructor` de su clase.
2. se llama al método `ngOnChanges` (si se ha implementado) si tu componente tiene inputs y estos varían.
3. se llama al método `ngOnInit`, donde se deben obtener datos de los servicios asociados al componente
4. se muestra el componente (su vista), generando el DOM y todos los event listeners asociados.

Hay más pasos (y métodos asociados) pero no es necesario para esta respuesta exponerlos y generalmente no son implementados.

El escenario que tenemos es que tu componente *padre*, para pasar los datos al componente *hijo*, necesita obtenerlos primero. Seguramente lo hará en su método `ngOnInit` a través de un servicio.

Generalmente esto implica una llamada asíncrona resuelta con un Observable. Por tanto, mientras la respuesta es obtenida, el componente hijo tiene un input (`data`) vacío, porque el padre aún no ha obtenido los datos. Una vez que el componente padre ha obtenido los datos, estos son compartidos con el hijo.

Tu componente hijo no implementa `ngOnChanges()`, lo que te permitiría detectar el momento en el que los datos son añadidos sin necesidad de usar `setTimeout`.